# Changing between UITableViewCells in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am new to UITableViews, and I dont know very much about this topic.

I have two buttons  in the same View, but not in the Table, for control the switch between the UITableViewCells, when one button is pressed then set a boolean for load the specific Cell.

- If you click the button 1 then it shows the table with the CellType1.
- If you click the button 2 then it shows the table with the CellType2.

My goal is use the same Table for this. But I dont know where to start.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";
if (clickButton1 == true)
    {
        clickButton1 *cell = (clickButton1*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            //cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CellType1" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }
        cell.name.text =  @"Trial";
        return cell;
    }
    else if (clickButton2 == true)
    {
        clickButton2 *cell = (clickButton2*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            //cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CellType2" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }
        //cell.name.text =  @"Trial";
        return cell;
    } else
```

I think that this code is not the best. But I am lost at this point.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you want those buttons to be cells in your tableview first? buttons in another view or buttons in your view but not in the table? you will need two different arrays or sets of information to load up either way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using a tutorial example like this...

```
//3</pre>
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section        {
return [self.tweetsArray count];
}

//4
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 //5
 static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"SettingsCell";

 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
//6
NSString *tweet = [self.tweetsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//7
[cell.textLabel setText:tweet];
[cell.detailTextLabel setText:@"via Codigator"];
return cell;
}
```

if you have two arrays for items such as self.tweetArray1 and self.tweetArray2 you could change this code to

```
//3</pre>
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section      {

int i = buttonNumberClicked;
return [self.tweetsArray[i] count];
}

  //4
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:   (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
//5

int i = buttonNumberClicked;

static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"SettingsCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
//6
NSString *tweet = [self.tweetsArray[i] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//7
[cell.textLabel setText:tweet];
[cell.detailTextLabel setText:@"via Codigator"];
return cell;
}
```

and set up ibactions for your buttons to change the variable/int buttonNumberClicked to 1 or 2 depending on which was pressed and [tableView reloadData]; inside ibaction as well, hope this helps.

Comment: I accept your answer! I dont know the method [tableView reloadData]. I made a research about it and works!! I have to connect my table with IBOutlet for can use it and make the stuff with the buttons. Thanks a lot!